# Trying to hide a frame with jquery when menu is hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, frames

I have a page with a frameset that consists of two frames; a top frame and a bottom frame. The top frame has a menu with submenus. The problem I am having is that the bottom frame does not allow the submenus to drop down as they should. I could expand the size of the top frame but management does not want this. Since it appears to not be possible to have the dropdown menu flow over the bottom menu, the best way I can think of to make it work is to hide the bottom frame while expanding the top frame. This is theory only though. I have never worked with asp.net or frames before so, to be honest, I'm not sure if it will work or not.

There is a separate page for the frameset and frames and it looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="dhss.mohsaic.webapplication.mohsaic.DefaultFrameset" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MOHSAIC</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Images/bavicon.ico"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio.NET 7.0" />
        <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="Visual Basic 7.0" />
        <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript" />
        <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" />     
    </head>
    <frameset border="0" framespacing="0" rows="95,*" name="frameset" class="frameset" id="frameset">
        <frame src="<%=HeaderFrameURL%>" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" name="fraHeader" />
        <frame src="<%=EntireBodyURL%>" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" name="fraEntireBody" id="bottomFrame" />
    </frameset>
</html>
```

The the html of the menu, which in a separate file is:

```
<div>
    <table id="tblAreaTabs" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;
        margin: 0px; padding-top: 0px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="DarkHeader" width="100%" bgcolor="#000000">
                    <asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" Runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        DynamicMenuItemStyle-CssClass="ChildLink" StaticMenuItemStyle-Font-Underline="true" StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="ParentLink" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" 
                        style="text-align:center;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=2, OffY=2, Color='black', Positive='true');">
                    </asp:Menu>
                </td>
                <td valign="middle" class="DarkHeader">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlError" runat="server" NavigateUrl="DssStatus.aspx" Target="fraDssStatus"
                        ImageUrl="/images/error.gif" BorderWidth="0px" Height="15px">The connection to DSS is not available.</asp:HyperLink><asp:HyperLink
                            ID="hlWarn" runat="server" NavigateUrl="DssStatus.aspx" Target="fraDssStatus"
                            ImageUrl="/images/warn.gif" BorderWidth="0px" Height="15px">The connection to DSS is partially available. </asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

the submenus are created dynamically depending upon the login credentials of the user

I have tried several ways to do what I want to do. The first was to add onmouseover="whileHovering()" to the asp:menu tag and add the following javascript:

```
 var origCols = null;
function whileHovering() {
    //alert("Yes, I'm working");
    if (origCols !== null)
        showFrame();
    else
        hideFrame();
};

function hideFrame() {

    var frameset = parent.document.getElementById("frameset");
    origCols = frameset.rows;
    frameset.rows = "120, 0";   
};
function showFrame() {
    document.getElementById("frameSet").rows = origCols;
    origCols = null;
};
```

However, this did not work. I receive the error 'cannot read property 'rows' of null. After investigating, the frameset is null and nothing I did would change that. So I gave up on that route and tried:

```
(function() {
    alert("I have entered the function")
    $('#mainMenu').hover(function () {
        alert('hidden function working')
        $(this).parent.document.getElementById('bottomFrame').style.visibility = "hidden"
    }), function () {
        alert('visible function working')
        $(this).parent.document.getElementById('bottomFrame').style.visibility = "visible"
    }               
 });
```

I get no errors from this but nothing happens. It doesn't even hit the anonymous function.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you put $ before `(function()` in your code?  `$(function() {})` fires when the document has been parsed and is ready, without it your function won't work. Also you don't need to use `getElementById('bottomFrame').style.visibility` in jQuery, there are quite short and elegant way to edit css rules, using `css(property, value)`. Also don't forget to put `;` in the end of your statements. The whole code looks like this:

```
    $(function () {
        alert("I have entered the function");
        $('#mainMenu').hover(function() {
            alert('hidden function working');
            $(this).parent().css("visibility", "hidden");
        }, function() {
            alert('visible function working');
            $(this).parent().css("visibility", "visible");
        });
    });
```

**UPDATE**:
If I understood you correctly you want to hide `bottomFrame` when hover on MainMenu, then use this code:

```
    $(function () {
        alert("I have entered the function");
        $('#mainMenu').hover(function() {
            alert('hidden function working');
            $('#bottomFrame').css("visibility", "hidden");
        }, function() {
            alert('visible function working');
            $('#bottomFrame').css("visibility", "visible");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Ah shoot. That explains why it wasn't entering the function. Thank you. So it enters the function and then enters the function to hide the frame when I hover over it. Unfortunately, it doesn't do anything.  I tried your code and it works but it works on the wrong frame. I need to it hide the bottom frame. Thank you for the code though because it made me see that parent isn't doing what I though it was going to do

Comment: @comfortablyNumb You're welcome. Could you try again please? There was 1 little syntax error, which I fixed (missing ) parenthesis )

Comment: It hides the wrong frame. It hides the top frame that the menu is in perfectly. What I need it to do is hide the bottom frame. Any idea how I can access that frame? document.getElementById('bottomFrame').style.visibility = "hidden" doesn't work. I tried replacing your .parent() with $(this).document.getElementById('bottomFrame').css("visibility", "hidden"); but it doesn't recognize the getElementById('bottomFrame')

Comment: @comfortablyNumb If I understood you correctly than please use code from UPDATE section.

Comment: #bottomFrame is a different frame altogether. Its not a present in current document that is being shown in parent frame. It will not be accessible this way.

Comment: $(window).parent().find('#bottomFrame').css("visibility", "_____"); might work. But not recommended.

Comment: @user2771704 - Nope. That didn't do it. Would it make a difference that the frame is in another file?

Comment: @VivekAthalye No, that did not work either. I'm going to go speak with management again. The MSDN even says that frames and framesets are obsolete. The really need to overhaul the app

Answer (score 0):

If you use frameset and frames you will have such problems. Writing JS/Jquery code is just a workaround and frankly not so good.

Any specific reason why you are using it?

Have you tried using ASP.NET master pages to have common menu and using it on different pages?
If that's not a feasible option, have you tried using iframe? In the main html file, create your menu and below the div/table tag of your menu, add an iframe. This iframe will show different pages that you are currently showing in #bottomFrame.

Comment: You're preaching to the choir sir! If I had my way I'd overhaul this whole darn site. It's ancient. However, I can only do what they allow me to do. I'm still trying to talk management into one of the avenues you have mentioned.